# Proving properties of the $\log$ function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So I know that $\log(x)$ is defined as:$\displaystyle \int_{1}^{x}\dfrac{1}{t}\,dt$ for $x > 0$.

I want to:

1. Prove $\log$ is a smooth function.
2. Prove that $\log(xy) = \log(x) + \log(y)$ for all $x, y > 0$. I have a hint that tells me to fix $y$ and define $f(x) = \log(xy) - \log(x) - \log(y)$, and show that $f(x) \equiv 0$.

I know these two statements to be intuitively true, and I know the derivative of $\log(x)$ to obviously be $\dfrac{1}{x}$, which I can take the derivative of over and over again, but how do I precisely prove statement (1)? Furthermore, for statement (2), I've substituted the definition of $\log$ to produce:

$\displaystyle \int_{1}^{xy}\dfrac{1}{t}\,dt - \int_{1}^{x}\dfrac{1}{t}\,dt - \int_{1}^{y}\dfrac{1}{t}\,dt \equiv 0$, but I am stuck at how to proceed next. Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You know that
$$
\ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt
$$
1. It follows from the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) that
$$
\frac{d\ln(x)}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}
$$
2. To find $\ln(xy)$, just write
$$
\ln(xy) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t}dt + \int_x^{xy} \frac{1}{t}dt
$$
and make the substitution $u = t/x$ in the second integral to recover $\ln(y)$

Answer (score 0):

We have $\log(x+h)-\log(x)-\frac{1}{x}h = \int_x^{x+h} (\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{x}) dt$. Let $\epsilon>0$.  Since $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is continuous, we have some $\delta>0$ such that if $|t-x|< \delta$, then $|\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{x}| < \epsilon$. Consequently, if $|h| < \delta$, we have 
$|\log(x+h)-\log(x)-\frac{1}{x}h| \le \int_x^{x+h} |\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{x}| dt  \le \epsilon h$, from which it follows that $\log$ is differentiable and $\log'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Since $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is smooth, it follows that $\log$ is smooth.

For the second part, follow the advice given and fix $y$, and define $f$ as above. You have $f(1) = 0$, $f$ is smooth, and using the chain rule, $f'(x) = \frac{1}{xy} y - \frac{1}{x} = 0$. Hence by the mean value theorem, $f(x) = f(1)$ for all $x >0$.

Alternatively, $\log(xy) = \int_1^{xy} \frac{dt}{t} = \int_1^{x} \frac{dt}{t}+ \int_x^{xy} \frac{dt}{t} = \log x+ \int_x^{xy} \frac{dt}{t}$. Using the substitution $s = \frac{t}{x}$, we get $\int_x^{xy} \frac{dt}{t} = \int_1^{y} \frac{ds}{s} = \log y$.